# When should i make a function async

Tags: reactjs, function, asynchronous, axios

I have a function that books an interview, using axios.  The function returns the axios put request to another function.  It's advising me to make the function asynchronous.

```
function bookInterview(id, interview) {
  const appointment = {
    ...state.appointments[id],
    interview: { ...interview },
  };

  const appointments = {
    ...state.appointments,
    [id]: appointment,
  };
  return axios
    .put(`/api/appointments/${id}`, { interview })
    .then((response) => {
      setState({
        ...state,
        appointments,
        days: getUpdatedDays(appointments),
      });
    });
}
function save(name, interviewer) {
  const interview = {
    student: name,
    interviewer,
  };
  transition(SAVING);
  props
    .bookInterview(props.id, interview)
    .then(() => transition(SHOW))
    .catch((error) => transition(ERROR_SAVE, true));
}
```

Should bookInterview be changed to be async, if so why is that the case.

Comment: What's "it" that's advising you? A linter? Maybe the advice is to use `async`/`await` rather than `then`?

Comment: this may be converted to an async function.ts(80006) when i hover over the function. everything works fine but I just want to know if i should make it async.

Comment: No, but you can